# C++ "undefined reference to..."

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I cannot figure out why my code is breaking, and I could use some help.

First of all, the code:

Timer.h:

```
#include [...]

class Timer {
    public:
        [...]
        Timer operator+(double);
        [...]
    private:
        [...]
        void correctthedate(int day, int month, int year);
        [...]
};
```

Timer.cc:

```
#include "Timer.h"
using namespace std;

[...]

void correctthedate(int day, int month, int year) {
    [...]
}

[...]

Timer Timer::operator+(double plush) {
    [...]
    correctthedate(curday, curmonth, curyear);
    return *this;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the error:

```
Timer.o: In function `Timer::operator+(double)':
Timer.cc:(.text+0x1ad3): undefined reference to `Timer::correctthedate(int, int, int)'
```

Any pointers in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Time / Timer? You have a mix here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following line:

```
void correctthedate(int day, int month, int year) {
```

should read

```
void Timer::correctthedate(int day, int month, int year) {
```

Otherwise you're just defining an unrelated function called `correctthedate()`.

Comment: Anybody who's ever made this mistake before, raise your hands: !_!

Answer (score 5):

Write

```
void Timer::correctthedate(int day, int month, int year) {
```

Your `correctthedate` definition is a free function, albeit one without a prototype. You have to qualify the name with `Timer::`

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
void correctthedate(int day, int month, int year) {
```

With this:

```
Timer::correctthedate(int day, int month, int year) {
```

In your version, `correctthedate` is just an ordinary function, it just so happens that it has the same name as one of the methods of `Time`. `Time::correctthedate` is a completely different function (method) which doesn't have a definition, so the linker complains it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Your header declares a  `Timer::operator+` and a `Timer::correctthedate` function.
Your cpp defines a `Timer::operator+` and a `::correcttehdate` function.
The linker can't find `Timer::correctthedate`.

The answer is to change `void correctthedate(int...` to `void Timer::correctthedate(int...`.